# Flutter Firestore Chat - Multiple Chats

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am building a student-tutor app where each question a student asks leads to a chat session between the student and the selected tutor. So if the same student and tutor answer a different question, it should be a different session.

What are some best practices to structure the firestore data collection for such a situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a chatrooms collection that combines the id's of student + tutor + question so you can guarantee that id will be unique for each chat session and inside every document you can have a subcollection called messages where you store timestamp of the message, the user that send the message etc.